# Looking for resources to study the design practices for Asian countries like china, taiwan etc

Tags: website-design, resource-recommendations, mobile

I am a visual designer and I have recently got this project on researching web/app design practices for Asian countries e.g. China, Taiwan, Japan, Korea etc. I have been trying to search for books or other resources but couldn't find one. I hope someone can refer me some resource to study the same.

For instance: If I need to design a mobile application for China, I need to understand how does the design work in China. E.g if Red is to stop, green is to go in USA, what is standard people follow in countries like china, Japan etc. How do they deal with the Typography and what are some best practices for the local user of those countries and how it is different than from western countries. 
I would be working on web/mobile app designs. I hope someone can guide me.

Comment: I‘d be interested too and I don‘t think the question is too broad. If this place shouldn‘t be an application-oriented forum but rather a place for doing „real“ visual design (others then „How do I generate that hyped look I want to copy“ for the 2385th time) then this is exactly the type of question I‘d expect here. Though I have no experience on that Far East market and can‘t deliver any input besides the fact, that if the orientation of the writing style is different to the western one, then this would also affect the way you have to design there.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question with an instance, but the moderator isn't paying attention? But on the bright side thanks for the support @Daiaiai. I hope someone answers this.

Comment: We moderators *can*, but seldom *do* 'hammer' questions closed or, similarly, 'hammer' them open again. Please understand that we are only 5, and that we do not keep tabs on the hundreds of questions we get here each week.

Comment: @Vincent now that I got your attention can you please "hammer" it open ..Thanks..this is genuine question and would help many designer who work remotely for audiences they don't know. Don't you think?

Comment: That's not the way it works. The question has been nominated for reopening, so users with sufficient reputation can vote whether to actually reopen it--that how Stack Exchange works. I'm not going to reverse the decision of another mod without hearing their reasons first.

Comment: This is too broad because you literally asked, "I need to understand how design works in China, Japan and Taiwan." Narrowing it down to one country does little to help. Imagine if someone asked, "How does design in America work?" -- we would still close it as way too broad. You need to ask about a specific concern say, "I'm using a Red and Black color scheme but am not sure if it has any meaning in Asia that I may be unaware of?" Or "I am designing for a Japanese market, are their phones typically the same resolution as Americans?" as examples.